# Simulation via C+GSL parallel with that via R

Tags: c, r, gsl

I use R to do simulation in my research work.
Recently, I turn to C+GSL for speed reason.
For illustration, I first write some 
simple codes via R as follows.

```
    n = 10
    nsim = 20
    out = array(0,c(nsim,1))
    set.seed(123) # for reproducibility
    for (i in 1:nsim){
        d = rnorm(n, mean=1, sd=0.1) # generate data
        m = mean(d)
        out[i] = m
    }
    print(out)
```

Then I try to use C+GSL to do the same thing, which reads

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stddef.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <math.h>
    #include <time.h>
    #include <gsl/gsl_vector.h>
    #include <gsl/gsl_matrix.h>
    #include <gsl/gsl_blas.h>
    #include <gsl/gsl_linalg.h>
    #include <gsl/gsl_rng.h>
    #include <gsl/gsl_randist.h>
    #include <gsl/gsl_statistics.h>

    int main(void){
        const gsl_rng_type * T;
        gsl_rng * r;

        int i, j, n=10, nsim=20;
        double d[n], out[nsim];
        double mean = 1, sigma = 0.1;

        gsl_rng_env_setup();
        T = gsl_rng_default;
        r = gsl_rng_alloc (T);

        for (int i = 0; i < nsim; i++) {
            for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
                double d[j] = mean + gsl_ran_gaussian(r, sigma);
                // printf (" %f", x);
            }
            double out[i] = gsl_stats_mean(d, 1, n);    
        }   
    printf ("The output is %g\n", out);
    gsl_rng_free (r);
    return 0;
    }
```

But something about my C+GSL codes is wrong. I am quite new to C+GSL. Any help?

Comment: `double d[j] = mean + gsl_ran_gaussian(r, sigma);` This should give you massive amounts of compiler errors. Did this really compile? I very much doubt so, or your compiler is trash.

Comment: @Lundin Yes, you are quite right. There were indeed many compiler  errors, but  I don't know how to correct them.

Comment: Then you need to mention this when you post the question, and preferably also post which line that gave the error and what the error was.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    double d[j] = mean ...
```

this keyword `double` now declares a *new* array `d` of doubles of size `j`. That is not what you want; you have already declared your array: drop the keyword `double` here.

Also drop the keyword `double` in `double out[i] = ...`

Note that in `printf ("The output is %g\n", out);` `out` is an array, but you can't print an array in one go; you have to print it one-by-one, so something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nsim; i++)
    printf ("%g\n", out[i]);
```

---

So your code could look like (only relevant parts):

```
    double d[n], out[nsim];
    ...
    for (int i = 0; i < nsim; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            d[j] = mean + gsl_ran_gaussian(r, sigma);
        }
        out[i] = gsl_stats_mean(d, 1, n);    
    }   
    for (int i = 0; i < nsim; i++)
        printf ("%g\n", out[i]);
```

Comment: Thanks! I correct  the`printf out` stuff following your help, but there are still something  wrong with compiling ` double d[j] = mean + gsl_ran_gaussian(r, sigma);` Any idea? I use the Cygwin with `gcc -Wall -std=c99 sim.c  -lm -lgsl -lgslcblas -o sim`.

Comment: John, see my addition to show you what the code should be like.

Comment: John, now remember that inside a __block__ (between `{` and `}`) keywords of type (such as `int` or `double`) create a new variable. That was your major error. Glad to have been of help.